# StandardML factorial evaluation enters infinite loop in Poly/ML REPL

Tags: recursion, sml, polyml

The following factorial function is well and good...

```
Poly/ML 5.8.3 Development (Git version v5.8.2-297-g8185978a)
> fun fact 0 = 1
# | fact n = n * fact(n-1);
val fact = fn: int -> int
> fact 2;
val it = 2: int
>
```

But the following takes the Poly REPL into infinite loop.

```
Poly/ML 5.8.3 Development (Git version v5.8.2-297-g8185978a)
> fun fact 0 = 1
# | fact n = n * fact n-1;
val fact = fn: int -> int
> fact 2;
```

Wondering what could be causing this??

Comment: I think it could be because of precedence of function application... I think..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ForceBru already gave an adequate answer, for completion, here is an example of evaluating this by hand that should reveal the infinite recursion:

```
fact 2 ~> 2 * fact 2-1
       ~> 2 * (2 * fact 2-1)-1
       ~> 2 * (2 * (2 * fact 2-1)-1)-1
       ~> 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * fact 2-1)-1)-1)-1
       ~> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

`n * fact n-1` is the same as `n * (fact n) - 1` - thus, `n` is never decreased, and your code ends up calling `fact 2` over and over and over again.

Comment: To elaborate, function application has a higher precedence than other operators. This is often useful. Consider writing a condition `if fact 2 < face 5 then ...`. This is much nicer than `if (fact 2) < (fact 5) then ...`. But it does mean a few extra parentheses in your case to make sure the subtraction happens before the function application.

Comment: Apologies... Not sure how I overlooked comments from you guys..

Comment: It happens. Just means A. you figured it out, and B. you got a nice confirmation. Good work.